# Partial TreeView refresh after EF model ItemsSource update

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, refresh

I have an Entity Framework model and TreeView which has a binding with model.

in constructor:

```c#
 Context.TestCategory.Load();
```

my TreeView:

```wpf
<TreeView x:Name="DbTree" ItemsSource="{Binding Context.TestCategory.Local}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Tests}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ContextMenuOpening="ContextMenu_ContextMenuOpening">
                        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu>
                                <MenuItem Header="Добавить тест" Click="TestAdd" CommandParameter="{Binding 
                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                     AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"></MenuItem>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock.ContextMenu> 
                 </TextBlock>
........................................
other items
........................................
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
       </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

After updating items in ItemsSource I need to update the related TreeView branch, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure binding your `ItemsSource` directly to a context property is a great thing to do.

What you're supposed to do with binding is bind to a property that can do `RaisePropertyChanged` when it has changed, and then the UI elements will update if needed. I use MVVM so my binding is all from a ViewModel which is the datacontext for the View, and which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Then within that my property setter can look like this:

```
    private List<TestCategories>_myItemSourceList;
    public List<TestCategories> MyItemSourceList
    {
        get { return _myItemSourceList; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _myItemSourceList)
            {
                _myItemSourceList= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => MyItemSourceList);
            }
        }
    }
```

And the XAML would look like ...

```
<TreeView x:Name="DbTree" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSourceList}">
```

Obviously because you're not using MVVM your code will be slightly different, but the principle remains: bind your `ItemSource` to a property that can `RaisePropertyChanged`.

EDIT: My RaisePropertyChanged is within the Prism framework, so is using a lambda, but the 'standard' was is with a string like this `RaisePropertyChanged("MyItemSourceList")`